# How to create a photo gallery view with the images which is in my application documents directory folder?

Tags: ios, ios4, three20, photo-gallery

I am saving photos in application folder, now I need to show these saved photos in a gallery view in my application, I've given a try to **Fgallery**, but it was not worthy as this is showing only local(Main bundle's) and network (server) images.I need to show my **application folder's images** in gallery View, and I don't know how to use **Three20** library. Please help.

Comment: Dear Naina did you manage to create your own photo gallery? please add the solution here. I want the same thing but I didn't manage to find anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ALAsset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for showing the photos from the iPhone Photo Album . You can refer this sample Code [ELCImagePicker](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its not helping..i need to create a gallery view with the images which is in my application documents directory folder.